# CmfRoutingBundle & PHPCR-ODM Custom Translation Strategy

Tags: symfony, translation, symfony-cmf, doctrine-phpcr

I'm trying to put together the following phpcr structure, which consists of freezing out certain versions of documents as references that are then pushed to external system apis for translation. Once a translation is complete for a locale it is sent back and the relevant locale node is updated with translation content and version reference.

```
ROOT:
    mstr:
        a-doc
    ref:
        a-doc:
           1.0:
           1.3:
           1.7:
    locale:
        es-ES
           a-doc
```

So thats all up and working.

Now I'm adding the CmfRountingBundle, and can't figure out how to get the locale routing to work (the add locale pattern option).

I figure I have to create a custom TranslationStrategy, and in my case I just need the loadTranslation method to find the related document in the locale path.

So this is what I've got:

```
<?php

namespace My\Project\Translation\TranslationStrategy;

use Doctrine\ODM\PHPCR\Translation\TranslationStrategy\TranslationStrategyInterface;
use Doctrine\ODM\PHPCR\Mapping\ClassMetadata;
use PHPCR\NodeInterface;

class CustomTranslationStrategy implements TranslationStrategyInterface
{
   /**
    * {@inheritdoc}
    */
   public function loadTranslation($document, NodeInterface $node, ClassMetadata $metadata, $locale)
   {
       throw new \Exception('Load translation not yet implemented ...');
   }
   ....
```

I added a translator attribute to my document:

```
/**
 * @PHPCR\Document(
 *   versionable="full",
 *   translator="custom",
 *   mixins={"mix:created", "mix:lastModified"}
 * )
 */
class Page implements ContentInterface, VersionableContentInterface {

    /**
     * The language this document currently is in
     * @PHPCR\Locale()
     */
    protected $locale;
```

Updated my config.yml

```
parameters:
    translation_locales: [zh-CN,de-DE,es-ES,fr-FR,it-IT,ja-JP,ko-KR,en-UK,en-US]

doctrine_phpcr:
    session:
        backend: "%phpcr_backend%"
        workspace: "%phpcr_workspace%"
        username: "%phpcr_user%"
        password: "%phpcr_password%"
    odm:
        auto_mapping: true
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        locales:
            en: [de, fr]
            de: [en, fr]
            fr: [en, de]
            #es: [en]

cmf_core:
  persistence:
    phpcr: 
        translation_strategy: My\Project\Translation\TranslationStrategy\CustomTranslationStrategy
    # if you want another basepath
    # basepath: /custom/basepath
    publish_workflow: false

cmf_routing:
    chain:
        routers_by_id:
            cmf_routing.dynamic_router: 20
            router.default: 100
    dynamic:
        locales: %translation_locales%
        persistence:
            phpcr:
                use_sonata_admin: auto
                content_basepath: /mstr
                admin_basepath: /cms/routes
        templates_by_class:
            %my_page_document%:  MyDemoBundle:Page:simple.html.twig
```

Now when I go to /fr-FR/a-doc I just see the english content of the document and when i go to /es-ES/a-doc I get a 500 error:  The locale 'es-ES' is not present in the list of available locales (i have it commented in the odm locales).

I'm obviously missing the $dm->setTranslationStrategy call the documentation mentions, just not sure how to inject it into the cmf routing bundle so that I get my Exception in loadTranslation.

Any advice on how i can get this working?!

Comment: the translation_strategy you can configure on cmf_core is meant for something different: force all models in your application to use a specific strategy (see http://symfony.com/doc/current/cmf/bundles/core/persistence.html#choosing-a-global-translation-strategy)

Comment: looking at the https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrinePHPCRBundle , a configuration option to add custom translation strategies is missing. can you open an issue there, or even open a pull request? (happy to discuss this further on github if you want)

Comment: and did you see the version api? the ref: section looks a bit like you are reinventing that in userland. its only supported in jackalope-jackrabbit at the moment, but could be implemented in jackalope-doctrine-dbal too

Comment: @dbu thanks for the reply. I am using jackrabbit, i want this custom workflow because i want a versioned master record that is independent and the translation procedure to be frozen reference nodes and independent versioned locale nodes. 

Ideally i want to just be able to override/configure the way the routing bundle finds the translation node.

Comment: Will open an issue on github, but perhaps it belongs in the CmfRoutingBundle? And will investigate more this week and see if i can pin point a solution to open a pull request

Comment: great. i will reply tomorrow on https://github.com/symfony-cmf/RoutingBundle/issues/282 and https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataDoctrinePhpcrAdminBundle/issues/148#issuecomment-69318490